# Authenticate using email and uuid

Tags: django, authentication

I have a custom authentication model that contains a `uuid` field. In case the user forgets his password, a link will be sent to his email that will allow him to reset the password. The link contains the `uuid`. The form contains only `password1` and `password2` fields.

Is there any way to change the password when user is not logged in ?(`auth.authenticate` cannot be used as the user does not remember his/her password.)

If not, I want to authenticate using his `email` and `uuid` itself. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is built into Django. See the [password reset view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) and the subsequent reset_done and reset_confirm views.

Submitting the form in the initial view will email a one-time link to the user, which when clicked will display a form allowing them to enter a new password without knowing the old one.

Comment: Hi, the function is built to reset the password. What if I want the user to confirm his identity by receiving the email sent by the server to create an new account(I mean `register confirmation`)?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comments to other answers. But this functionality is provided by a number of third-party apps, see https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/registration/